# Convert Dictionary to a list of Tuples

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How to convert in the shortest way a dictionary to a list of tuples(C#) ?

```
Dictionary<long,int> myDico = new Dictionary<long,int>();
IList<Tuple<long, int>> applyOnTree = myDico.Something();
```

Comment: How about `IList<Tuple<long, int>> applyOnTree = myDico.Select(i => new Tuple<long, int>(i.Key, i.Value)).ToList();` ?

Comment: Just curious, may I ask why? What can you do with 2-tuples that you can't do with key/value pairs?

Comment: I wanna have a duplacted value for  my firstType<firstType,secondeType> impossible in a dictionnray

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var list = myDico.Select(x => new Tuple<long, int>(x.Key, x.Value)).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks this's exactly what i was looking for, i have to wait 12 min to give to accept the answear 
i also have no idea why i got -1 the question doesn't exist in stackoverflow

Comment: `ToList()` method does not have this overload method in `System.Linq` namespace.Which namespace we have to add for using this overload method?

Comment: Don't use `new Tuple`. `Tuple.Create` is less verbose because it infers the types.

Answer (score 4):

you can try this

```
var applyOnTree = myDico.Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.Key, x.Value)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of an [tuple type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples):

```
IList<(long First, int Second)> applyOnTree;

applyOnTree = myDico
   .Select(x => (
      First: x.Key, 
      Second: x.Value))
   .ToList();
```