# Convert Dictionary values to Tuple

Tags: c#

I have a `Master` class with an object below:

```
public class Master
{
     public List<Conditions> Conditions { get; set; }
}
```

And `Conditions` class is shown below:

```
public class Conditions
{
    public int AccountBalance { get; set; }

    public int Rating { get; set; }
}
```

So the `Conditions` object could accept a JSON like the format below

```
Conditions :[
    {
      "accountBalance": 400,
      "rating": 5
    },
    {
      "accountBalance": 200,
      "rating": 10    
    },
       ...
    ]
```

I am trying to convert it to list of int tuples so that only the values are taken to create the tuple. So the the expected result:

```
[(400,5),(200,10),...]
```

The tuple class I have is

```
public class Result
{
     public List<Tuple<int,int>> Conditions{ get; set; }
}
```

My focus is primarily in python so forgive my question if it's too simple

Comment: Do you have some *JSON* to convert?

Comment: No It's a list of dictionaries using classes and objects

Comment: it's unclear if you wana get list of `Tuple<int,int>` or `"[(400,5),(200,10),...]"` string

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. I want a list, not string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Dictionary to a list of Tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59561915/convert-dictionary-to-a-list-of-tuples)

Answer (score 2):

in old good style

```cs
var l = new List<(int, int)>();
foreach(KeyValuePair kv in myDict)
    l.Add((kv.Key, kv.Value));
```

of course, there is some "sugary" stuff like

```
List<(int accountBalance, int rating)> l = new List<(int, int)>();
```

in this case, you will see `x.accountBalance` instead of `x.Item1` in intellisense

But I believe, what you have is JSON that should be loaded into the list of models like

```cs
// using Newtonsoft libraries

public class MyModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "accountBalance")]
    public int AccountBalance {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "rating")]
    public int Rating {get; set;}
}

// your list looks like
var l = new List<MyModel>();
```

Once you have code above ^^^ why would you need tuple? But you can convert your model list to tuple, in you need that

Comment: I have updated the question to make it clear if that helps

Comment: @AshA So, if you already have the list of the `conditions`, what is the issue? My answer shows how to do the loop. The syntax you have `List<Tuple<int,int>>` is not necessary in the latest frameworks. Just do `List<(int x,int y)>`. This will give you named items for syntactic sugar.

Comment: @TS I tried this way but I still get the key name ("accountbalance"..etc); however, I only want the value in the tuples (e.g. [(400,5),(200,10)]). So no key names, just values

Comment: @AshA **you don't understand** - "key name" is just a syntactical sugar in your code editor. At runtime you have a value type that consist of 2 integers

Comment: @AshA https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/august/essential-net-csharp-7-0-tuples-explained

Comment: var list = myDico.Select(x => new Tuple<long, int>(x.Key, x.Value)).ToList();

Answer (score -1):

With plain old collections and foreach loops.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Dictionary<string, int>> list_of_dicts = new List<Dictionary<string, int>>() {
            new Dictionary<string, int>() {
                {"accountBalance", 400},
                {"rating", 5}
            },
            new Dictionary<string, int>(){
                {"accountBalance", 200},
                {"rating", 10  }  
            }};

            List<Tuple<int, int>> int_tuples = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

            foreach (Dictionary<string, int> dict in list_of_dicts)
            {
                int_tuples.Add(new Tuple<int, int> (dict["accountBalance"], dict["rating"]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```